# Envoyproxy misses some dynamic upstream clusters properties in config_dump

Tags: tls1.2, envoyproxy, tls1.3

I'm using Envoy and trying to create a dynamic configuration using [Sovereign](https://github.com/cetanu/sovereign) control-plane. I add a section *match_typed_subject_alt_names* into config and then on the envoy side call */config_dump* and this section is just not present. Don't understand what happens.

Config on the Sovereign side looks like I expect it. This is what I see when use Sovereign UI to check what config it sends to Envoy (some parts of the config removed):

```
{
  resources: [
    {
      name: "name1-elb",
      type: "STRICT_DNS",
      load_assignment: {
        cluster_name: "name1-elb",
        endpoints: [
          {
            lb_endpoints: [
              {
                endpoint: {
                  address: {
                    socket_address: {
                      address: "host1.net",
                      port_value: 443
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                endpoint: {
                  address: {
                    socket_address: {
                      address: "host2.net",
                      port_value: 443
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      transport_socket: {
        name: "envoy.transport_sockets.tls",
        typed_config: {
          @type: "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext",
          max_session_keys: 0,
          allow_renegotiation: false,
          common_tls_context: {
            tls_params: {
              tls_minimum_protocol_version: "TLSv1_2",
              tls_maximum_protocol_version: "TLSv1_3"
            },
            validation_context: {
              trusted_ca: {
                filename: "/etc/ssl/certs/certificates.crt"
              },
              match_typed_subject_alt_names: [
                {
                  san_type: "DNS",
                  matcher: {
                    exact: "host1.net"
                  }
                },
                {
                  san_type: "DNS",
                  matcher: {
                    exact: "host2.net"
                  }
                }
              ],
              allow_expired_certificate: false
            }
          }
        }
      },
      @type: "type.googleapis.com/envoy.api.v2.Cluster"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is what I see when use /config_dump on the envoy side:

```
{
  dynamic_active_clusters: [
    {
      cluster: {
        @type: "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.cluster.v3.Cluster",
        name: "name1-elb",
        type: "STRICT_DNS",
        transport_socket: {
          name: "envoy.transport_sockets.tls",
          typed_config: {
            @type: "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext",
            common_tls_context: {
              tls_params: {
                tls_minimum_protocol_version: "TLSv1_2",
                tls_maximum_protocol_version: "TLSv1_3"
              },
              validation_context: {
                trusted_ca: {
                  filename: "/etc/ssl/certs/certificates.crt"
                }
              }
            },
            max_session_keys: 0
          }
        },
        load_assignment: {
          cluster_name: "name1-elb",
          endpoints: [
            {
              lb_endpoints: [
                {
                  endpoint: {
                    address: {
                      socket_address: {
                        address: "host1.net",
                        port_value: 443
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  endpoint: {
                    address: {
                      socket_address: {
                        address: "host2.net",
                        port_value: 443
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        respect_dns_ttl: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, no match_typed_subject_alt_names section is present. I also tried to add different matchers with no success.

Any ideas what happens there?